# Completely disable AppSettings in WPF app?

Tags: wpf, performance

Consider any `WPF` app, targeting any `.NET` version (including `.NET 5`). On application load, nearly **half a second** is wasted in reading/parsing of `AppSettings`.

**Q:** Is it possible to completely disable the `AppSettings` system in a `WPF` app?

As can be seen in [BaseCompatibilityPreferences.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/BaseCompatibilityPreferences.cs,23) the `AppSettings` object is hit immediately upon type initialization (static constructor). This is where a performance hit can be observed:

[image: Performance hit on startup]

I can imagine that an antivirus scanner could be involved here, since this involves reading from disk. Anyway, I'm wondering if we can completely get rid of this cost. Ideas?

Comment: Is 1/2 second really all that critical on app startup?  If you display a splash screen (as I do), the perceived loading time will be much lower, because the user will have something to look at while the app loads.

Comment: Critical or not. A Hello World app should not spend 1/2 second on reading a setting file.

Comment: My rule about performance problems is I only fix them if there's an actual performance problem.  I don't fix things "just because," and in a real app, you've got bigger problems to solve.

Comment: If you ( maybe take a copy first )  delete app.config out your solution. Clean before running. Does it still spend half a second now you got nothing to read from?

Comment: .NET Core/.NET 5 is no longer using app.config to configure the runtime. Therefore I assume that the absence of the app.comfig should do it (like Andy suggested). Anyway I can't remember that even when using app.config that this was ever an issue. Maybe in times of HDD. But I can't remember.

Comment: I did not add any settings, so there is no `app.config`. Perhaps `BaseCompatibilityPreferences` touches some framework-level `.config`. It's not a super big deal, but I've always wondered why a simple `win32` app would always start much faster than a simple `WPF` app. Ten years later it's starting to clear!

Comment: @RobertHarvey Seems reasonable. In this case, we have a requirement to show a `UI` immediately when the user runs the app. The observed delay is visible (and a tiny bit annoying), hence my question here. Certainly there are ways to mitigate this (e.g. keep `exe` running in the background), but it's still embarrassing (for Microsoft) that a Hello World app does *not* start in a blink of an eye.

Comment: You have posted the source code yourself: there is no framework level .config. The framework tries to query the app.cofig to check for user settings that configure the runtime. If there are non, an exception is thrown by the Configurationmanager. This process take only a few ms. if you expand the next GetSection node you would be able to see this. It's impossible that this code portion takes that long. The actual time is spent on configuring the application's runtime and not in the constructor of `BaseCompatibilityPreferences`.

Comment: Knowing that there is a runtime running to host the WPF application the extra configuration makes sense. Java runtime is even slower. Anyway, the perceived startup time is the "blink of an eye". If it is not then you have slow I/O or were starting the application after a machine boot (cold start). If you want the start up of a "Hello World" faster, then don't use WPF i.e. don't use the WPF runtime and instead write an unmanaged application that uses native Win32 .

Comment: But I have to say that when starting a blank or tiny WPF application then normally there is no observable delay - even when some configfuration like logger or IoC is going on. Also there is adifferent when running the application in debug vs release mode. Maybe this can help you to improve your startup time: [Microsoft Docs: Application Startup Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/application-startup-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).